# How to pass path to Link if others items are null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a array like this for the React Router Link, It is rendering as expected but when I click on any of the path the web is crashing, and in the console it's saying pathname is null.. How to make sure that even the link key is not provided it should work

```
const items = [{
    label: "Home"
    link: "/home"
  }, {
    label: "SubMenu"
    links: [{
      link: "/sub"
    }]
  },
  {
    label: "SubMenu1"
    links: [{
      link: "/sub1"
    }]
  }
]
```

I am using **React router dom**

after **.map**

```
<Link to={items.link}>
</Link>
```

Comment: How are you mapping the `items` array? What other items being null are you referring to? Please include all relevant code in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

please try it:

```
const route=items.map((elem)=>(
<Link to={elem.link}>
{elem.label}
</Link>
```

Comment: You are simply returning link.. if there's no link provided it will throw error

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that it's not null, do this

```
<Link to={`${elem?.link}`}>
  {elem?.label}
</Link>
```